# React Native Firebase causes Xcode couldn't find 'include/core/SkData.h' file

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-firebase

Actually, with firebase-ios-sdk v9+ (react-native-firebase v15+) you ***must*** tell CocoaPods to use frameworks. using `use_framework` causes several issues, one of them is this: Xcode cannot find `react-native-skia` header files.

On Xcode it shows itself by:

> 'include/core/SkData.h' file not found

On the terminal it would be like this:

> The following build commands failed:
> CompileC /Users/amerllica/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KidspodMobileClient-fmdzmtzitsgnloepiahdecibemvu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-skia.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SkiaManager.o /Users/amerllica/WebstormProjects/Dubit/Kidspod/node_modules/@shopify/react-native-skia/ios/RNSkia-iOS/SkiaManager.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'react-native-skia' from project

The project couldn't be built by using `use_framework`.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is modifying pod files before installation on the `Podfile` inside the `ios` folder, for doing this, open the `Podfile` and then make a list of pods that you want to change:

```
# Convert Skia pods into static libraries
$static_library = [
 'react-native-skia/Api',
 'react-native-skia/Jsi',
 'react-native-skia/RNSkia',
 'react-native-skia/SkiaHeaders',
 'react-native-skia/Utils',
 'react-native-skia',
]
```

And then add the following codes after the above codes:

```
pre_install do |installer|
  Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}

  installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    ## Skia pod correction
    if $static_library.include?(pod.name)
      puts "Overriding the build_type to static_library from static_framework for #{pod.name}"
      def pod.build_type;
        Pod::BuildType.static_library
      end
    end

    ## Firebase
    bt = pod.send(:build_type)
    puts "#{pod.name} (#{bt})"
    puts "  linkage: #{bt.send(:linkage)} packaging: #{bt.send(:packaging)}"
  end
end
```

Please after this change, inside your `ios` folder run the `pod install` command again and then try to build your project.